# What does "it is the looming turnaround" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the sentence mean that "**the market** is now interested in an imminent complete change in monetary policy elsewhere"

“The market seems bored with the Fed and, instead, **it is the looming turnaround in monetary policy elsewhere** that’s driving currencies — and pushing the dollar down,” said Steven Barrow, London-based currency and fixed-income analyst at Standard Bank, in a note."

Source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/is-janet-yellen-still-calling-the-tune-in-financial-markets-2017-07-10

Comment: The market expects a drastic change in policy. The sentence does not imply  that the market is interested in it, merely that the market expects it to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Grammatically* the clause in bolded print has nothing to do with "the market" or its bordedom, inasmuch as there are two independent clauses here connected by **and**.   *Semantically*, however, the phrase "driving currencies" is related to the idea of "the market", since the passage is about currency trading. If there is activity in the currency trading market, it comes from an impending reversal of monetary policies elsewhere in the world -- the market isn't paying much attention to the Fed.